# Graphic issue on intel945 chipset

Tags: 12.04, compiz, intel-graphics

I used Intrepid(8.10) and my graphics used to work fine with compiz effects and all(on better resolution than 1024x768).Now I have upgraded to Precise(12.04)but I use gnome classic(with compiz effects)as my desktop but the compiz effects seem not to work, only unity 2D works.

**When I ran `lshw -c video` it gives:**

> *-display UNCLAIMED

```
   description: VGA compatible controller
   product: 82945G/GZ Integrated Graphics Controller
   vendor: Intel Corporation
   physical id: 2
   bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
   version: 02
   width: 32 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list
   configuration: latency=0
   resources: memory:fea80000-feafffff ioport:dc00(size=8) memory:e0000000-efffffff memory:fea40000-fea7ffff
```

**Sysinfo shows:**

```
Display
Resolution       1024x768 pixels
OpenGL Renderer  Gallium 0.4 on llvmpipe(LLVM 0x300)
X11 Vendor       The X.Org Foundation
```

**On SystemSettings:**

- Memory    993.3 MiB
- Processor Intel® Pentium(R) 4 CPU 2.40GHz
- Graphics  VESA: Intel(r) 82945G Chipset Family Graphics
- OS type   32-bit

`glxgears` output comes to be around 100fps which used to be around 900fps in Intrepid

Comment: You could also try Ubuntu **10.04 LTS**. *What are the specs of your hardware?  (CPU, RAM, HDD)

Comment: Intel® Pentium(R) 4 CPU 2.40GHz with 945G/GZ chipset,1GB of RAM,40GB of HDD
Is there nothing that can be done in 12.04?

Comment: The specs are fine to run either **10.04 LTS** or **12.04 LTS**. This is simply about a better intel-graphics driver, or ***if*** that chipset will support 3D and other effects. **Unity** (3D) is *heavy* and uses transparency, scaling, and transform *to great affect*. You may just need to buy a graphics card.